# How to navigate to a function in current buffer in Clojure mode

Tags: emacs, clojure

I would like to know if it is possible to get a list of the functions that are defined in the current buffer and quickly select a specific function (like CMD-R does in Sublime Text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clojure-mode` has built-in support for imenu. Just call `imenu-add-menubar-index` to create an index menu with entries for each def. Or call `imenu` to select a def with auto-completion.

Comment: This and adding idomenu provides exactly what I need.

Comment: Is there a way to get this working for "defn" macro? Most of functions are declared with that...

Answer (score 1):

You need two packages - `helm` and `clojure-semantic`.
First one you can get from MELPA, second one from [here](https://github.com/kototama/clojure-semantic).
The setup is under a minute.

Finally, making sure that `semantic-mode` is running in your Clojure buffer, just
call `helm-semantic`.